# Is there a way to alter Zend Studio PhpDoc preferences?

Tags: zend-studio

I'm trying out Zend Studio trial and I have a few things on my mind related to PhpDoc.

If I have the following code:

```
public function sum($a, $b)
{
 echo $a + $b;
}
```

and then I start typing /** in the front of the function and press Enter, Zend Studio automatically makes the following text:

```
/**
 * [cursor]
 * @param unknown_type $a
 * @param unknown_type $b
 */
```

However, I want to customize this so that it also includes @return void automatically since there's no return inside the function. Is there a way to do this? And what about things like @access? It's obviously "public".

Another thing I want is that when I create a new file and I use the code templates with ${user}, it will use my Windows account, but I want it to use something else - is there a way to specify this "user"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Zend.com](http://www.zend.com/en/) has good documentation, including [Code Templates Preferences](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/code_templates_preferences.htm) for Zend Studio.

[image: zend preferences]

Because it's eclipse based, you may find useful tips at places like:

1. [Getting started with Eclipse code templates](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/edu/os-dw-os-eclipse-code-templates.html)
2. [PHP Developer Tools template idea](http://2tbsp.com/node/104)
3. [Using Eclipse Templates](http://www.ericbutera.us/post/view/18)